# ListView Nativescript, appears 1/3 of the screen instead of full page

Tags: android, listview, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to display the listview on the full page but it is just appearing in the one-third.

[image]

Thats the listview code:

```
<ListView [items]="dataItems" (setupItemView)="onSetupItemView($event)" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-dataitem="item" let-i="index" let-third="third" let-header="header" let-footer="footer">
        <GridLayout [class.third]="third" [class.header]="header" [class.footer]="footer" class="list-group-item">
            <StackLayout>
                <Image src="https://i.imgur.com/muf3HZM.png" stretch="none"></Image>
                <Label [text]="dataitem.name" android:class="label-item"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try wrapping it with a gridlayout like this

```
<GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
    <ListView col="0" row="0" [items]="dataItems" (setupItemView)="onSetupItemView($event)" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)" class="list-group">
        <ng-template let-dataitem="item" let-i="index" let-third="third" let-header="header" let-footer="footer">
            <GridLayout [class.third]="third" [class.header]="header" [class.footer]="footer" class="list-group-item">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image src="https://i.imgur.com/muf3HZM.png" stretch="none"></Image>
                    <Label [text]="dataitem.name" android:class="label-item"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </GridLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped.